# How to write to a local printer in golang without a buffer?

Tags: linux, go, thermal-printer

I have a thermal printer connected via USB at `/dev/usb/lp0`. I want to print a label by writing my EPL (Zebra commands) to this file. But the printer doesn't receive all the written bytes. I suspect some kind of buffering but don't know hot to avoid it.

I have a working java example:

```
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("/dev/usb/lp0");
fo.write(bytes, 0 , bytes.length);
fo.flush();
fo.close();
```

But my go code doesnt't work:

```
f, err := os.OpenFile("/dev/usb/lp0", os.O_RDWR, 755)
if err != nil {
   return err
}

n, err := f.Write(bytes)
if err != nil {
   f.Close()
   return err
}

log.Printf("Wrote %d bytes", n)

return f.Close()
```

Putting the printer into Trace mode, I found out, that the printer receives only the first 128 of
181 bytes. When I add a second write method after the first line, like this

```
f.WriteString(" ")
```

the sequence get printed as submitted. Using `f.Sync()` to flush doesn't work, because it's not supported for files like `/dev/usb/*`. How do I correctly write to the printer without using a second write method?

Comment: How many bytes does your program report that it wrote?

Comment: n is always 181 (if the []byte has a length of 181), but only the first 128 where printed.

Comment: Since 128 bytes is a magic number (2^7) it suggests your printer has some buffering and/or timing requirements. What happens if you split your `bytes` array into chunks no larger than 128 bytes and add a short sleep between writing chunks?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but I encountered something similar to this issue earlier this week. I couldn't figure out why my receipts weren't being cut by a USB POS printer consistently. Sometimes they would, sometimes they wouldn't. It dawned on me that my Golang program might be executing too quickly, clearing the buffers and terminating before the printer had received all the necessary commands. So, I decided to introduce a short delay (because sync does not work like the OP said) for testing purposes, and it worked.
So, I'm leaving this comment here in case someone else encounters the same issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).